# Changing pages with StackedWidget via button isn't working

Tags: c++, qt

I am very new to QT so trying to get my head around how things so it is more than likely I am using the wrong tools for the job so please feel free to say if I am.

Now, what is wanted is a GUI that is basically a way to run a set of pre-determined test steps. So I have a main page that lists the options (as buttons) and when a button is selected it goes through to another page (that may also have a number of pages, I haven't decided yet) returning to the main page eventually.

So as I am changing form page to page I thought QStackedWidgets here seemed an approach that would be appropriate

So it's all via Qtcreator so far, I created some UI form pages for each option and created a stackedWidget that has as many pages as forms here. Each page is promoted to be the form that I want. My main page then has some buttons

But I am not sure how you tie a button into changing the page. I added a clicked signal to the button and then did this:

```
ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(1);
```

But it didn't change and I am not sure I am happy about hardcoding the pages in this way anyway.

But am I missing something obvious in how you connect pages like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [signals and slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html). Basically each time you push a button, there signals which are triggered (like the [clicked](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) signal). You can connect to a custom slot, which will then change the stacked widget. For example, the slot can do

```
index = (index + 1) % numStacked;
ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(index);
```